# Statement after while not executing in the client program

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I am trying to read a file from server and able to do it successfully. However, at the client end the statement after the while loop does not execute at all. Kindly help me with this request. The line asking for client input does not show up at all. Please help

```
//Client Side Code
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.lang.*;

public class oss_client1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2222);
        char n1;
        int choice;

        // reading the file name from keyboard. Uses input stream
        BufferedReader keyRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));
        BufferedReader dis = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        // receiving the contents from server. Uses input stream
        InputStream istream = sock.getInputStream();
        InputStream istream1 = sock.getInputStream();


        // sending the file name to server. Uses PrintWriter
        OutputStream ostream = sock.getOutputStream();
        BufferedReader dRead = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(istream));
        BufferedReader socketRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                istream1));


        PrintWriter pwrite = new PrintWriter(ostream, true);
        PrintWriter pwrite1 = new PrintWriter(ostream, true);

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter the website name: ");
            String u_input = keyRead.readLine();
            pwrite.println(u_input);
            String str;

            while ((str = dRead.readLine()) != null) {
                // reading line-by-line
                System.out.println(str);
            }


            str = dRead.readLine();
            System.out.println(str);
            dRead.close();

            System.out
                    .print("\nPlease enter the product code which you want to buy: ");

            String pcode = dis.readLine();
            pwrite1.println(pcode);
            String pcode_res = socketRead.readLine();

            System.out.print("\nBack from server " + pcode_res + "\n");
            System.out.println("\nDo you want to continue(Y/N)");
            String n = dis.readLine();
            n1 = n.charAt(0);

        } while (n1 == 'Y' || n1 == 'y');

        pwrite.close();
        socketRead.close();
        keyRead.close();
    }

}
```

//Server side code

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class oss_server1 {
    static Socket clientSocket = null;
    static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    static clientThread t[] = new clientThread[10];

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        int port_number = 2222; // The default port

        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("Now using port number=" + port_number);
        } else {
            port_number = Integer.valueOf(args[0]).intValue();
        }

        /* Try to open a server socket on port port_number (default 2222) */
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        while (true) {
            try {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
                    if (t[i] == null) {
                        (t[i] = new clientThread(clientSocket, t)).start();
                        port_number++;
                        break;
                    } // end of if loop
                } // end for looop
            }// end of try loop
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        } // end of while loop

    }
}

class clientThread extends Thread {


    DataInputStream is = null;
    DataOutputStream dout = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    clientThread t[];

    public clientThread(Socket clientSocket, clientThread[] t) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Welcome to US ONLINE SHOPPING SYSTEM");
            String website = "www.US_OSS.com";

            // buffer stream for reading the choice from client
            InputStream istream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            InputStream istream1 = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader webRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));
            BufferedReader pcodeRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));


            // buffer stream reading the file contents
            BufferedReader displayRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "display_client.txt"));
            BufferedReader prodRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "product_list.txt"));

            // keeping output stream ready to send the contents
            OutputStream ostream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter pwrite = new PrintWriter(ostream, true);
            String str, str1, pcode;
            String fname = webRead.readLine();
            if (fname.compareTo(website) != 0) {
                pwrite.println("Error 404: NOT FOUND");
            } else {
                while ((str = displayRead.readLine()) != null) // reading line-by-line from file 
                {
                    pwrite.println(str);
                }
                displayRead.close();
                str = "END OF PRODUCT LIST";

                pwrite.println(str);
                pcode = pcodeRead.readLine();
                System.out.print("\nReceived PCODE is: " + pcode);
                pwrite.println(pcode);
            }
            // pwrite.close();
        } // end of try block
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    } // end of run class
}// end of Client thread class
```

Comment: My mistake on my first reply, I read too quickly. I deleted it. I'll re-read the code now.

Comment: One reason could probably be some `Exception` !

Comment: Salute to the code formatter :-)

Comment: But, the semicolon is necessary. otherwise it results in a syntax error

Comment: can you post the relevant code? its too much of code. Also can u point out which `while` loop gets stuck ?

Comment: i am closing the buffer stream that reads the file at the server side. But also the statement "System.out.print("\nPlease enter the product code which you want to buy: ");" does not execute

Comment: @sanbhat 
client side
while((str = dRead.readLine()) != null)
        { 
            //reading line-by-line 
        System.out.println(str); 
        }
        str = dRead.readLine();
        System.out.println(str);
        dRead.close();
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter the product code which you want to buy: ");
This line does not execute at all

Comment: Are you sure that the `while` condition ever evaluates to `false`?  If it doesn't, then the while loop will never end and so the statements after it *won't* be run.

Comment: i get the file contents at the client side completely from the server. but the next line after that.. does not execute..

Comment: @user2582322 One thing to note is that you are invoking `readLine` after your `while` loop.  This is at best pointless because the loop enuures that you are at the end of the stream.  It may even cause an exception, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: @ViktorSeifert the readLine after the loop executes as well, but the program is fixed with the socket buffers, it is not coming out of it and priniting the local client statement

Comment: at server, when i close the client output buffer pwrite.close... all the client statements executes but there is socket closed exception caught at the server side...

Answer (score 1):

`BufferedReader` when reading after `EOF` will issue `IOException`

Instead I suggest you use `Scanner` to read files
Your code would look like...(in ServerSide)

```
Scanner scnFile=new Scanner(new File("display_client.txt")); //give absolute path if necessary

while(scnFile.hasNext()){

System.out.println(scnFile.nextLine());

}

scnFile.close();
```

Comment: replace `catch()` 's body with `e.printStackTrace();` and run

Comment: I think in your actual code on server side crashes  silently due to exception

Comment: @boxed__l +1 to that comment.

Comment: tried that as well... the next line after getting the file contents is still not executing... wen tried to use pwrite.close in server, then the line executes, but the socket itself gets closed :-(

Comment: @user2582322...I forgot to add File object pls see the updated code

Comment: @boxed__l: no go, same problem. it is waiting for the server socket to release the contorl :-(

Comment: @user2582322 are you sure client is not waiting for console input because of `keyRead.readLine();`? During initial run is the client asking `Do you want to continue(Y/N)`?